# How to remove consecutive duplicate records from datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
ID  Name
1   A   
2   B
3   A
5   A
6   A
7   B
10  B
```

From these records I want only below records, Is it possible?

```
ID  Name
1   A   
2   B
3   C
4   A
7   B
9   C
10  B
```

Comment: where did `ID=3`/`C` come from? and where did `ID=4/A` and `ID=9/C`come from?

Comment: If you are using Linq to interact with your database, you should be able to use .Distinct() whenever you use the Name column and 'get rid' of the duplicates that way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're asking about removing contiguous (when considered ordered) values.

If we assume that the `ID` values should be treated as continuously increasing without gaps, it can be done pretty easily - just do a left join back to yourself and demand that the previous row has a different value, or the previous row doesn't exist (to include the first row):

```
select cur.ID, cur.[Name]
from @data cur
left outer join @data prev on prev.[ID] = cur.[ID] - 1
where prev.ID is null or prev.[Name] <> cur.[Name]
order by cur.ID
```

It is trickier if we *don't* assume the `ID` values need to be contiguous; here I'm using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to simulate it:

```
select cur.ID, cur.[Name]
from (select ID, [Name], Row = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) from @data) cur
left outer join (select ID, [Name], Row = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) from @data) prev
    on prev.[Row] = cur.[Row] - 1
where prev.ID is null or prev.[Name] <> cur.[Name]
order by cur.ID
```

There may be much better ways.

In both of these, I'm using:

```
declare @data table (ID int not null, [Name] char(1) not null);
insert @data (ID, [Name]) values (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'A'),(5,'A'),
    (6,'A'),(7,'B'),(8,'B'),(9,'C'),(10,'B');
```

which seems to match your expected output (but not your stated input)